# Google index iframes on Facebook fan pages? (Hole website content)

Tags: seo, facebook, duplicate-content, iframe, facebook-application

I have a fairly simple question that I've tried to get help from the guys on the [*Google Webmaster Help Q&A*](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en) site but so far no joy so hopefully someone here can provide me with the information I'm looking for.

I have a Facebook fanpage for my website, I have made an app that basically uses an iframe and puts the site within a frame within Facebook. All works good but Google is not indexing this page.

I am using `<link rel="canonical" href="#" />` on my pages so prehaps this is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here that are:

- Duplicate Content Served Via (iFrame).
- Canonical Links

Google does not take favorably to indexing pages that are duplicate and basically the iframe your using is duplicate of your own website, also Google may not want to inex this pages because of the canonical links contained within the iFrame.

Your best action is to ignore that its not indexed as it's likely not going to serve any purpose since you want your site found and not that of the Facebook App, the other option would be to make an actual app page that is not duplicate and designed for Facebook and differs from your own site.

Generally a lot of businesses have Fanpage designed for them and they do not stick the entire site in Facebook, since there shouldn't be any need.

A similar question on Stack Overflow: [Does Google index iframe content as part of your site or part of the site where the content is from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967773/does-google-index-iframe-content-as-part-of-your-site-or-part-of-the-site-where)